# How to implement photo collage on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on photo collage project on Android. I want to know how to implement the following collage effect?

[image]

So there are two photos will fit into each triangle.

or more complex shape like this: (this will hod 5 photos)
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that easy.

One solution would be to remove the unwanted pixel of your image like the following snippet from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234443/1484047)  (cuts off the top right corner):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image);
    int drawableId = R.drawable.your_drawable;
    cutOffTopRightCorner(iv, drawableId, skewWidth);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void cutOffTopRightCorner(ImageView iv, int resId, int skewWidth) {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    bm.setHasAlpha(true);
    final int bmWidth = bm.getWidth();

    for (int i = bmWidth; i > bmWidth - skewWidth; --i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < i - (bmWidth - skewWidth); ++k) {
            bm.setPixel(i - 1, k, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Another solution would be to work with FrameLayouts (differenz z-indices) and to overlay your images with other images or drawables.

You can also have a look into [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650740/divide-image-into-parts)

Comment: The first link is broken